# Defining structs in Apples Metal framework

Tags: ios, c++11, metal, compute-shader, memory-layout

I am playing around with Metal for iOS making a little game. In one of my kernel shaders (in my .metal files). I am defining a struct to hold some of the metadata for the part of the game play.

The struct looks as such:

```
struct ColorSetup {
    float4 color;
    float4 degradationColor;
    float degradationRate;
};
```

This works perfectly fine but when I try adding more fields to my struc such as:

```
struct ColorSetup {
    float4 color;
    float4 degradationColor;
    float4 threshholdColor;
    float degradationRate;
};
```

The code misbehaves and seems to not be able to use some of the fields. At this point the new fields is not being used. My first thought was that it had to do with memory alignment of the struct. I was under the impression that correct padding would be added by the compiler but still went ahead and tried to align the size of the struct properly myself (ordering the fields in descending order and aligning the struct to 48 and 64 bytes), but without any success. I also tried using packed data types to avoid alignment issues, still without success.

I know that the logic is correct as I have written the same logic without using the struct and then ported it over to using the struct to hold data with the exact same behavior. But at this point adding any fields to it breaks it. Also, keeping the original struct but using packed datatypes also breaks it in similar way.

```
struct ColorSetup {
    packed_float4 color;
    packed_float4 degradationColor;
    float degradationRate;
};
```

So this definitely seems like a memory layout issue, but I am unclear how to solve it without working around the issue.

Any thoughts or ideas I can try out?

Edit:

The data is not passed into my compute shader through a MTLBuffer but is simply defined in constant memory space inline in the .metal file as such:

```
constant ColorSetup redColor = {
    .color = red,
    .degradationColor = white,
    .degradationRate = 0.0035
};
```

Edit 2:

Trying to describe some more findings and what the code is actually doing.

The function in question that breaks is a method that is suppose to fade colors based on values provided in this struct.

```
float4 degrade(float4 color, ColorSetup colorSetup, ColorLimit colorLimit) {
    float4 targetColor = colorSetup.degradationColor;
    float rate = colorSetup.degradationRate;
    if (colorLimit.degradationThreshold.r < color.r && colorLimit.degradationThreshold.g < color.g && colorLimit.degradationThreshold.b < color.b) {
        targetColor = colorSetup.degradationColor;
    } else {
        targetColor = colorSetup.color;
    }

    int r = (color.r - targetColor.r) < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    int g = (color.g - targetColor.g) < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    int b = (color.b - targetColor.b) < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    float4 newColor = float4(color.r + float(r)*rate, color.g + float(g)*rate, color.b + float(b)*rate, 1);
    return normalizeColor(newColor);
}
```

This function works as expected when I have the struct defined as:

```
struct ColorSetup {
    float4 color;
    float4 degradationColor;
    float degradationRate;
};
```

If I add a float to it (Even if I don't read it anywhere and it is not part of any caluculation. This is just to try to figure out where the bug is).

```
struct ColorSetup {
    float4 color;
    float4 degradationColor;
    float degradationRate;
    float padding;
};
```

At this point it still works just fine if I don't specify the new float in the construction as such.

```
constant ColorSetup redColor = {
    .color = red,
    .degradationColor = white,
    .degradationRate = 0.0035,
};
```

But if I do this:

```
constant ColorSetup redColor = {
    .color = red,
    .degradationColor = white,
    .degradationRate = 0.0035,
    .padding = 0
};
```

The above specified function stops working and the colors don't fade anymore.

Another interesting observation is if I use an int instead everything works:

```
struct ColorSetup {
    float4 color;
    float4 degradationColor;
    float degradationRate;
    int padding;
};
```

Comment: If you capture the frame (Debug > Capture GPU Frame) and inspect the contents of the buffer, do they match your expectations? How are you copying the data into the buffer on the client side? Are you using Objective-C or Swift? If Objective-C, are you sharing the struct definition (doesn't look like it), or do you have a parallel struct definition in Obj-C?

Comment: @warrenm thanks for your reply. To clarify, this is a struct that is defined and created in constant memory space in my .metal file. None of the data is coming from my swift code and NOT passed to my compute shader through a MTLBuffer. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting twist. Unfortunately, I was not able to see any unexpected behavior when trying this out myself in a test project. Can you more precisely characterize the problems you're seeing or provide additional context?

Comment: @warrenm I have added an Edit2 with a lot of details and findings.

Comment: @warrenm Oh. Just realized. I bought and read your book Metal By Example. Good job. Very nice starter.

Comment: Thanks! I still can't reproduce this with the added detail, but there's a moderate chance this is a Metal compiler bug. Have you filed a report with Apple?

Comment: @Michel did you ever get to the bottom of this?